# Structuring new data when predicting via predict.merMod

Tags: lme4-nlme, gamm4

I am trying to obtain predictions, given new data, from within a loop using the `gamm4()` function in the mgcv package of R.  However, I run into an error message that makes no sense (to me ...).  I am hoping that someone can explain what is happening, and how to fix it.

I start with a list of `gamm4` objects:

```r
my.list <- list(
gamm4:gamm4(X1 ~ 1, random= ~ (1group), data=sim_normal.with.nesting, 
            family=gaussian),
gamm4::gamm4(X2 ~ X1, random= ~ (1|group), 
             data=sim_normal.with.nesting, family=gaussian),
gamm4::gamm4(X3 ~ X2,random= ~ (1|group), 
             data=sim_normal.with.nesting, family=gaussian),
gamm4::gamm4(X4 ~ X3, random= ~ (1|group), 
             data=sim_normal.with.nesting, family=gaussian))
```

There are 5 columns and 1000 rows in the data frame (sim_normal.with.nesting).  Inside the loop I extract the relevant regression object via:

```r
choose.reg <- my.list[[this.regression]]
```

where "this.regression" is a counter in a for() loop over the gamm4 objects in the list.  I create a new data frame (called new.dat) that has exactly the same dimensions as the original data frame ("sim_normal.with.nesting").  I have checked and this is the case.  I then attempt to get predicted values using the new data: `fit<-predict(choose.reg, newdata=new.dat,type=scale)`.

I then get the following error message:

```r
> Error in predict.merMod(choose.reg, newdata = new.dat, type = scale) :
dims [product 200] do not match the length of object [1000]>
```

What does this error mean?  It cannot mean that the dimensions of "new.dat" are different from those of the original "sim_normal.with.nesting" because the two are identical.

Comment: gamm4 objects are just a list with flavours of the underlying model, so don't you want `choose.reg <- my.list[[this.regression]]$gam` (or `$lmer` IIRC for the mixed model version)